# ¿Cómo guardar en una variable la respuesta de un evento de Socket.io?

Tags: angular, socket.io

Quiero mostrar en pantalla al usuario el mensaje de 'Límite de equipos' cuando se ha alcanzado dicho límite, ese mensaje lo tengo en un `eventSubject`. Estoy intentando extraer dicho mensaje pero no logro hacerlo, de momento pruebo imprimiendo en consola el evento pero no obtengo nada.

Lo que quiero saber es ¿Cómo se extrae dicho mensaje 'limite-equipos'?

Variable evento de mi Socket.Service.ts

```js
  setEvents() {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      this.conectado = true;
      this.eventsSubject.next({ event: 'connect' })
    });


    this.socket.on('limite-equipos', () => {
      this.conectado = true;
      this.eventsSubject.next({ event: 'limite-equipos' })
    });
```

Mi Home.ts

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.events$.pipe(filter(event => event.event === 'limite-equipos')).subscribe(event => console.log(event));
  }
```